# Is there any techniques to print out the result of error code from the rest api to the client side

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am totally confused when I try to test my endpoint on my program in springboot under restcontroller layer, when i try to post a new data to test if the error code print out to the client side, it always record saved even though there are a expected invalid input in the payload .I try to test the prodID field, this field has a String data type but in the payload I put a number value to test if the error code will print out in the response of postman

here's my error code that expected to print out:

```
                response2.setErrorCode("ERR-011");
                response2.setErrorValue("ERR_VALUE_PROD_ID");
                response2.setErrorDescription("Error saving policy, please check value for 
                Prod ID [IS] - Instasurance");
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(response2);
```

here's my sample payload:

```
{
"registration_details": [
    {
        "intermediary_source_cd": "NA",
        "issuance_source": "BAYADCENTER",
        "branch_purchase": "Main Branch",
        "card_number": "NA",
        "insured": {
            "first_name": "Andrea",
            "middle_name": "Natividad",
            "last_name": "Bautista",
            "suffix": "NA",
            "civil_status": "S",
            "gender": "M",
            "email": "andreabautista@emailprovider.com",
            "mobile": "09681738347",
            "birth_date": "2023-02-23T06:31:01.088Z",
            "age": 9,
            "province": "Batangas   ",
            "city": "San juan",
            "zipcode": "123",
            "barangay": "Kawanggawa",
            "street": "san roque st.",
            "tin": "111-111-111-000",
            "nationality": "Filipino",
            "place_of_birth": "Lallo, Cagayan"
        },
        "policy": {
            "prod_id": 12,
            "policy_number": "AH-IS-MPBY-23-0000001-00-D",
            "cc_email": "bcs@bayadcenter.com",
            "branch_purchase": "Main Branch",
            "inception_date": "2023-02-23T06:31:01.088Z",
            "issue_date": "2023-02-23T06:31:01.088Z",
            "expiry_date": "2023-02-23T06:31:01.088Z",
            "gross_premium": 29.00,
            "premium_amount": 29.00,
            "accidental_medical_expense": true,
            "number_of_units": "1",
            "coverage_period": "1"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Here's my endpoint code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
@ApiOperation(value = "Medicash buy and register details", response = CustomApiResponse.class)
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully registered"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid input"), 
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "You are not authorized to view the resource"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Accessing the resource you were trying to reach is forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found") })
@PostMapping("/buyandregister")
public ResponseEntity<CustomApiResponse> buyandregister(
        @ApiParam(value = "Request payload", required = true)
        @Valid @RequestBody BuyAndRegisterRequest request) {
    displayObjects(new JSONObject(request));
    CustomApiResponse response2 = new CustomApiResponse();
```

try {
ObjMedicashInquiry objinquiry =
sqlService.getMedicashDetail(request.getDetails().get(0).getPolicy().getPolicyNo());

```
        if(objinquiry != null) {
            
            response2.setErrorCode("ERR-004");
            response2.setErrorValue("ERR_POLICY_EXISTED");
            response2.setErrorDescription("Policy number is already existed");
            
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(response2);
            }
        
        if(request.getDetails().get(0).getIssuanceSource().equalsIgnoreCase("BAYADCENTER")){
            
        
            if (!(request.getDetails().get(0).getPolicy().getProdId().equalsIgnoreCase("IS"))) {

                response2.setErrorCode("ERR-011");
                response2.setErrorValue("ERR_VALUE_PROD_ID");
                response2.setErrorDescription("Error saving policy, please check value for Prod ID [IS] - Instasurance");
                
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(response2);
            }
                
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }finally {
        response2.setMessage("Record saved.");
        response2.setStatus(true);
        response2.setReferenceno(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response2);
    }
}
```